# Feign Client with PCF internal route

Tags: java-8, spring-cloud-feign, feign, pcf

With Feign client I couldn't connect to an api endpoint hosted on internal route in PCF. Getting connection refused exception like below. Any advise on resolving this issue?

```
 feign.RetryableException: Connection refused (Connection refused) executing POST http://dev-myapp.apps.internal:8080/sendorder
2019-03-12T10:40:20.85+0800 OUT         at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:67) ~[feign-core-9.5.1.jar!/:na]
```

Code

```
@FeignClient(name = "myapp", url = "http://dev-myapp.apps.internal:8080")
public interface Client {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. Not an issue with the code. In PCF routing between the micro services were not configured. Once its done, it works

Comment: Am having the same issues. Can you please provide some more details about this fix

Comment: I was using internal routes. In this case, you gotta manually create the routes between different apps which you like to talk to. If you don't have internal routes, then PCF automatically set the routing between apps.